# Ghostscript tiffg3 gray=black

Tags: ghostscript

Trying to take a pdf and convert it to a tiff, but make all grayscale into pure black.  In other words, if it's not white, it should be black.  The tiffg3 device is 1 bit, but it's still taking gray and trying to fake it.

Example command:

gs -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r200 -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sDEVICE=tiffg3 -sOutputFile=out.tiff in.pdf

Example input:
[image]

Example output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 1-bit device uses halftoning (aka screening) to represent shades of gray using only black and white pixels. That's what its intended to do, its *not* intended to change colours at all.

There are various ways you can fake what you want in PostScript (redefining setgray is one method, also setting a transfer function), but PDF is not a programming language, so this approach doesn't really work.

You could use a custom ICC profile to colour correct gray values so that they are all black. Ghostscript versions 9 and above use Little CMS as the colour management system, and have a 'default' Gray ICC profile which you can override. Presumably it would be easy enough to construct a profile which maps anything other than white to pure black. However, this is not my field. You also need to consider how this is going to affect (for example) images.

There are additional  controls based on object type in Ghostscript, so you could optionally only apply this conversion to text, or linework.
Ideally you should go back to the original document, alter it there, and make a new PDF.

Comment: Any good places to start on the ICC profile stuff?  I've been googling, but this is also not my field... Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert from imagemagick for that purpose, using the flag -level. For example to convert an image to pure black/white splitting the gray scale in half:

convert -level 50%,50% file.pdf blackwhite.pdf

and then pass it to GS. My suggestion for fax though is to leave part of the grayscale there since many documents rely on it for its legibility:

convert -density 816x784 -level 55%,95% file.pdf blackwhite.pdf

This one leaves a 40% of the grayscale there, converts to black every dot in the range 0-55 (being 0 black and 100 white) and puts everything in the range 95-100 to white, you can play with that and get your best match. The density flag will help it later when converting to tiffg3 in GS giving a better quality in the resulting tif.